# search() javascript doesn't work if first character there isn't in the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

Hello I know that `search()` in javascript doesn't work (returns **-1**) if first charachter does not exist in the string...

```
$('#search-vulc').on('keyup', function() {
    var textinsert = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase();
    var nome_search = "home";

    if (nome_search.search(textinsert) != -1) {
        alert('ok');
    } 
    else {
        alert('not');
    }
});
```

And so in this example if we write "x home", returns -1.

But is there a way to "solve" this problem ? 
in short, if i write "**x home**" anyway there is the word **home**...

**I would like a method that in this case doesn't return -1**

Comment: It seems you want to swap the subject and the object: `textinsert.search(nome_search)`. Did you try that?

Comment: So if someone writes `x home` you want to ignore the `x`? Or search for `x` and `home` separately?

Comment: for me don't must return -1 if there is the word home... for me is not important if before word home there is "x" or another charachter

Comment: Is this `nome_search.search(textinsert)` simply backwards? `textinsert.search(nome_search)`

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for "x home" in "home".
Thus it is returning -1.

```
if (nome_search.search(textinsert) != -1)
```

Should be

```
if (textinsert.search(nome_search) != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this `nome_search.search(textinsert)` simply backwards? `textinsert.search(nome_search)`

Refactored code:

```
function getStringPostion(re, str) {
  var midstring;
  var position = str.search(re);
  midstring=(position != -1) ? ' contains ':' does not contain ';
  console.log(str + midstring + re);
  console.log(position );
  return position;
}
var foundAtPosition = getStringPostion("home","x home");
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterating trough all the inserted strings might do:

```
  var f = function(re) {
  var textinsert = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase().split(" ");

  var nome_search = "home";
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i<textinsert.length; i++){
    console.log(textinsert[i]);
    if (nome_search.search(textinsert[i]) != -1) result++;
  }
  return result > 0 ? alert('ok') : alert('not') ;
};
```

as long as they are separated by spaces like in your example.